# Spring Security: Authorization with domain logic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

**Prerequisite**

I'm using Spring Security to authenticate my users with firebase. During authentication I also extract the users roles from the JWT token and convert them into `SimpleGrantedAuthorities`.

In most cases I can use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to apply authorization to an endpoint. But now I have a more complex authorization scenario.

I have a `Service` that fetches a `Product`, but only users who have purchased the product are allowed to receive it.

```kotlin
fun fetchProduct(val id: Int, userId: String) {
  val product = productRepository.findById(id)
  
  // only users that purchased the product are allowed to fetch it!
  if (!product.isAccessibleAtNoCharge(userId) && !purchaseCheck.hasUserPurchased(userId, product.id)) {
    throw ForbiddenException("User has not purchased product")
  }
  return product
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

My requirement is, that users with the role `ROLE_ADMIN` can bypass that check, so that they can access products without purchasing them before.

**What I have tried**

My only idea so far is to retrieve the roles from `SecurityContext` like so:

```kotlin
fun fetchProduct(val id: Int, userId: String) {
  val product = productRepository.findById(id)
  
  val isAdmin = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.authorities.any { it.authority == "ROLE_ADMIN" }
  if(isAdmin) {
    return product
  } else {
    // check if purchased
    ...
  }  
}
```

**Considerations**

- I have doubts that this solution is well testable, because of the static method call
- I feel that the solution is not abstracted (mixing business logic and authorization logic)
- Usually authorization seems to be done in the controller, which is not possible in this case?

Do you have suggestions for alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to abstract away the authorization logic is to create a `PermissionEvaluator` and put authorization logic there.

```
@Component
public class ProductPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object id, Object role) {
        Long productId = (Long) id;
        Optional<Product> productOptional = productRepository.findById(productId);
        boolean isAdmin = authentication.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(a -> a.getAuthority().equals(role));
        boolean hasPurchased = // Logic to find if user has purchased the product

        return isAdmin || hasPurchased;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable id, String product, Object role) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use the PermissionEvaluator like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
public Product fetchProduct(Long id) { // Logic to fetch product }
```

You'll need to register the PermissionEvaluator as well, which you can do like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ProductPermissionEvaluator productPermissionEvaluator;
    
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        var expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(productPermissionEvaluator);

        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the other answer, you can define your own bean with custom authorization logic for your products and call it inside an **SPeL**.

```java
@Component
public class ProductPermissionEvaluator {

    public boolean canFetchProduct(Long productId, Long userId) {
        // perform your logic
    }

}
```

```kotlin
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') || @productPermissionEvaluator.canFetchProduct(#id, #userId)")
fun fetchProduct(val id: Int, userId: String) {
    ...
}
```